# Do Windows crypto APIs run slower on purpose with debugger attached to the process?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, hmac, cryptoapi

In my Windows application I needed to implement the [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) encryption for passwords. For that I needed to calculate [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code) using SHA-256 many times over. So for a single round of that I was calling the following sequence of APIs:

```
//For simplicity I'm not posting the full code
//One can look up implementation of HMAC/SHA-256 in C
CryptAcquireContext(, NULL, MS_ENHANCED_PROV, PROV_RSA_FULL, CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT | CRYPT_NEWKEYSET);
CryptImportKey(, , 0, CRYPT_IPSEC_HMAC_KEY, );
CryptCreateHash(, CALG_HMAC, , 0, );
CryptSetHashParam(, HP_HMAC_INFO, , 0);
CryptHashData(, , , 0);
CryptGetHashParam(, HP_HASHVAL, NULL, , 0);
CryptGetHashParam(, HP_HASHVAL, , , 0);
```

This sequence may be called on the order of 10,000+ times in a sort of a loop according to PBKDF2 specifications.

I started noticing though, that if I run this sequence via Ctrl+F5 (in Visual Studio), or without a debugger, it executes in about less than 1 sec on my laptop. But if I attach a debugger to the process, it runs painfully slow -- sometimes close to 10+ seconds or so. (The timing in this case is also inconsistent.)

So I thought that this happens because of a debugger build. So I tried building a release build and then attached a debugger. To my amazement it was also running slow.

So I'm curious, is there something in those crypto APIs that make them run slower with the debugger attached?

Comment: Do you notice any difference between starting the application under the debugger and attaching the debugger after it started?

Comment: @MatteoItalia: I just tried it and if I attach Visual Studio debugger to my running process, it doesn't seem to happen.

Answer (score 1):

> I just tried it and if I attach Visual Studio debugger to my running process, it doesn't seem to happen.

Then it depends from the Windows debug heap (not to be confused with the CRT debug heap, which is completely unrelated and is activated building in debug mode):

> Instead of using the standard heap API, processes that the debugger creates use a special debug heap. You can force a spawned process to use the standard heap instead of the debug heap by using the `_NO_DEBUG_HEAP` environment variable or the `-hd` command-line option.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh406274%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

For a more detailed explanation and some benchmarks, see [here](http://preshing.com/20110717/the-windows-heap-is-slow-when-launched-from-the-debugger/).